# Can Origin of Spanish DNA from 16th to 18th generations be traced to historical events?

Tags: dna, united-kingdom, autosomal-dna, spain, 16th-century

DNA on Ancestry & GEDMatch -- I find a bit of Spanish with a dash of some Mediterranean groups all dated to 16 or so generations back.  Else all British Isles with another dash of Northern European. No family history from that far back.

Is this King Philip's soldiers and sailors staying a while in Britain?  If so, how can I tell?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Is the period you are speaking of this one in the mid-16th century?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_II_of_Spain#King_of_England_and_Ireland

Answer (score 1):

Your only chance will be to perform an investigation and get information about your ancestor's origin from Spain (if they were from there!), after that you might be able to find military records from Spain to see if any of those ancestors were part of the army (if registers exist). Actually being a 16th to 18th generations, you might be talking about XV century kind of far from Armada.

I would say that the best chance is that your spanish ancestors were descendant from lower nobility that might as well descend from nobility which married with spanish nobility. That might be easy to evidence based on baptism records and nobility information. That's more likely than invaders getting married in the failled invasion.

Answer (score 0):

Such big distance in time can lead only to speculations. The only chance to connect historical events is to get solid proof. You can try to restore all available data like church books, historical documents and so on. Maybe you find something.

Also I want to say that the origin of Spanish DNA can be everywhere, also it can be just mistake of test.